# Product matching algorithms

Tags: api, commission-junction

I am using commision junction API to fetch data through different feeds provided by them...

I want to implement an algorithm to fetch similar products from different sellers..

Any help related for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a research paper from microsoft here: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/144534/matching_tr.pdf